# SVG paths not working when specified in Aurelia repeat.for

Tags: javascript, svg, internet-explorer-11, aurelia

I am using an SVG map of the united states in an Aurelia application. I would like to be able to iterate over a list of states and set the path in a repeat.for. This is working just fine in Chrome and Firefox, but fails miserably in IE11 with an error:

SVG4601: SVG Path data has incorrect format and could not be completely parsed.

I have an example set up in a Plunker at:

http://plnkr.co/edit/UpxgfS?p=preview

```
<template>
    <div class="map">
        <svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
        xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 959 593" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
        id="us-map">
            <g>
                <path repeat.for="state of states" id="${state.name}" d="${state.path}"></path>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</template>
```

It seems that Aurelia isn't even trying to bind the "d" property in IE11.

Any and all help appreciated!

Comment: Can you show what renders in the DOM?  Is there a different result in Chrome?

Comment: In Chrome and Firefox, the path is set correctly: d="M 471.87905,128.47084 L 471.4218,120.0118 L....." In Internet Explorer, d="" ... so it's not rendering anything in there. I bound it to a function call with console.log yesterday, and Chrome and Firefox both wrote out the expected stuff. In IE, the function was never called.

Comment: The rendered path element in IE (there are 48 of these, with different state names):
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="au-target" id="VA" d="" au-target-id="1" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `d.bind="state.path"`

http://plnkr.co/edit/OVIe2dKxTKrDPDEmIU2a?p=preview

Internet explorer is strict about what it allows in the `d` attribute-   `${...}` isn't allowed:

[image: error]

Notice the error and the `d` attribute is empty ^^^ after IE parses the HTML.

By the time Aurelia compiles your template the `d` attribute has been cleared by the IE's html parsing logic.